# Next.js TypeError: Class extends value #<Object> is not a constructor or null

Tags: next.js, document

I was try customizing _document

So I looked at the official document and wrote the code below, and the code below worked normally.

```
import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

export default function Document() {
  return (
    <Html>
      <Head />
      <body>
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
      </body>
    </Html>
  )
}
```

And I wrote the code below to customizing renderPage, but there was an error

```
export default class MyDocument extends Document {}
```

[image]

I don't know why there's an error

Comment: How are you importing `Document`? Make sure to import it from the default export, e.g. `import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'`.